# Pylance consuming too much memory, how to enable Jedi to get around this issue?

Tags: memory, python, visual-studio-code

My `Pylance` when I leave my `VSCode` running a `Python file`, every few minutes the number of ram memory used increases, reaching 100% usage on the pc.

I've seen some people indicating activating `Jedi` to solve this problem, but I'm not sure how I should go about it. As I understand it I don't need to install any extensions, I just need to add this code in the settings:

```
"python.languageServer": "Jedi"
```

Should I set in `settings.json` which I access via `F1` and then clicking `Open Settings (JSON)`? If so, the current settings look like this:

```
{
    "liveServer.settings.ignoreFiles":["**"],
    "workbench.editorAssociations": {
        "*.ipynb": "jupyter-notebook"
    },
    "notebook.cellToolbarLocation": {
        "default": "right",
        "jupyter-notebook": "left"
    },
    "workbench.iconTheme": "vscode-icons",
    "liveServer.settings.donotShowInfoMsg": true,
    "json.maxItemsComputed": 100000000000000,
    "git.enableSmartCommit": true,
    "git.autofetch": true,
    "git.confirmSync": false,
    "diffEditor.renderSideBySide": false
}
```

If the location where I should add the configuration is that, would it look like this (code below) or another way? (I added it to the end of the list, but I don't know if it's correct.)

```
{
    "liveServer.settings.ignoreFiles":["**"],
    "workbench.editorAssociations": {
        "*.ipynb": "jupyter-notebook"
    },
    "notebook.cellToolbarLocation": {
        "default": "right",
        "jupyter-notebook": "left"
    },
    "workbench.iconTheme": "vscode-icons",
    "liveServer.settings.donotShowInfoMsg": true,
    "json.maxItemsComputed": 100000000000000,
    "git.enableSmartCommit": true,
    "git.autofetch": true,
    "git.confirmSync": false,
    "diffEditor.renderSideBySide": false,
    "python.languageServer": "Jedi"
}
```

Will this solve my ram problem or did I get it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter where in the list you add it. I like to keep my settings in alphabetical order, but that's personal preference.

That said, the GUI settings editor is more user-friendly. I don't know what platform you're using, but on the Mac, `cmd+,` (command-comma) is the standard keyboard shortcut for opening preferences/settings, and by default VSCode uses the GUI (rather than the JSON) version.

(If you're not on a Mac, pull up the command palette and choose `workbench.action.openSettings`. And if you want to figure out the shortcut for next time, choose `Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts` and search for `workbench.action.openSettings`.)